# Move files from EXT to NTFS preserving symbolic links

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, symbolic-link

When I try to move lots of files from an EXT partition to an NTFS partition in Ubuntu, it complains about "Filesystem does not support symbolic links", and fails.  Of course NTFS *does* support symbolic links, so is there a way to move the files and preserve the links?

If not, is there a way to move the files and skip the links or convert them into regular files or something?

Comment: Is the `ntfs-3g` driver being used? If yes, which version?

Comment: @grawity: Ok, first problem: I wasn't really using NTFS; I was using vboxsf, which doesn't support symlinks.  I then created a NTFS VHD and mounted it in VirtualBox, and was able to move symlinks over, but they are in a Linuxy format, as a plain file starting with `IntxLNK`, which Linux still recognizes as links, but Windows does not. I'm not sure if it uses NTFS-3G when you double-click in Nautilus, but I would assume so.

Comment: 1) Those are Interix symlinks (not "Linuxy"). 2) ntfs-3g only applies when the disk is accessed directly; it's an entirely different matter if you access the filesystem over some kind of network. 3) You didn't say which version of Windows.

Comment: I *am* accessing the disk directly now, just wasn't when I asked the question.  I created a virtual NTFS drive to share between VirtualBox and Windows 7.  When I move the links to the NTFS partition, they are converted(?) into Interix symlinks instead of native NTFS symlinks.  Linux still seems to recognize them, but Windows does not.

Comment: "The similar concept of symbolic link is also available in Windows Vista. ... The symbolic links in Vista are different from Interix symbolic links created by ntfs-3g which are also interoperable with Windows XP and Vista." http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/junction-points-and-symbolic-links/

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix

Interix is an **optional**, POSIX-conformant Unix subsystem for Windows NT operating systems. Interix is a component of Windows Services for UNIX, and a superset of the Microsoft POSIX subsystem.
[...]
Interix versions 5.2 and 6.0 are respective components of Microsoft Windows **Server 2003 R2**, Windows **Vista Enterprise**, Windows **Vista Ultimate**, and Windows **Server 2008** as Subsystem for Unix-based Applications[1] (SUA[2]). Version 6.1 is included in **Windows 7 Enterprise and Ultimate** editions, and in Windows **Server 2008 R2 (all editions**).[3]

Have these Interix *optional* components been installed on you vbox?